# how to connect a hardware using a socket and which socket should be used for connecting to hardware

Tags: c#, networking

I don't know anything about network programming in C#? But I just want to connect a hardware device using socket and i want to know how to create a strong socket and how to connect to a hardware using socket and for connecting to the hardware which type of socket is used?
Please guide me or help me thanks in advance for your support thanks again

Comment: What do you mean by "strong socket"? And it's best you poke around MSDN or Google at least and do some research first. This posted question is very broad.

Comment: actually i create a socket but it gets off after some particular time so that's why i need to create a strong socket who remains active through out the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sockets are based on client/server architecture. The server will reserve a port number. Then it will listen to any upcoming client. The client then will attempt to connect to the server. When the connection succeeds, it will be possible to exchange text messages. When finished, the connection will be closed.

To use sockets in C# , we have to add the following using statements:

`using System.Net; 
using System.Net.Sockets;`

Then Create a socket object

```
Socket sListener;
```

For More, please go through the links ..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xzx2d41%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463947/Working-with-Sockets-in-Csharp

Comment: Thanks friend it means a lot to me thanks again